# Can we use an Identity-based signature for identity authentication?

Tags: signature

This is clear to me that message authentication is provided by a signature scheme. Can we use an Identity-based signature for identity authentication?

Comment: What's "identity authentication", and how does it differ from "entity authentication" and "message authentication"?

Comment: I am working on the same thing. Certainly you can use an identity-based signature for authentication-- but the question is whether or not signature scheme overqualifies. Can we optimize it since we don't need message authentication but entity authentication only?